# как превратить str в список на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

```
text = input()

print(type(text)) #str
```

как превратить str в list в python?

Comment: Ваш вопрос следует уточнить, так как строку можно превратить в список чего угодно - символов, слов/предложений (по сути других строк), чисел, объектов (кортежей/словарей/списков)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = input('some text >> ')

text = text.split('')

print(type(text)) #list
```

метод split превратил str в list